# What is the difference between GVI and DVI?

Tags: aircraft-maintenance

In any maintenance program I found some terms like General Visual Inspection (GVI) or Detail Visual Inspection (DVI) or Detailed Inspection (DTI). I want to know the difference between these types of inspection.

And which type of inspection is required in which cases.

Comment: Is that linked to EASA means of compliance? Related: [Clarification  of  Definitions  for  General  Visual  (GVI),  Detailed  (DET),  and Special Detailed (SDI) Inspections](https://www.easa.europa.eu/sites/default/files/dfu/IP122%20Rev%202.pdf)

Comment: Terms like these, when used in a manual, are usually defined within the manual itself.

Answer (score 1):

GVI is general visual inspection and when you make a GVI, you have to be maximum an arm's length distance to the area and/or component you are searching any defects.

DVI is detailed visual inspection, it depends to the situation but usually you use a tool like a magnifier to inspect the area/component.

Answer (score 1):

GVI and DVI can be differentiated by the distance of visual.

GVI is further back and overview of the whole area, doesn't fall under any zonal inspection.

While DVI is closer visual inspection, can be enhanced by using magnifying glass.

There is SDI special detail inspection, this inspection is to find hidden faults using non destructive testing (tap test/rotor test/dye penetrant/...)

When there is a finding on GVI, further DVI can be carried out. This follows the card that had been issued.

Comment: "This follows the card that had been issued." What is a card? Is this specific to a particular carrier's operations (if so you should specify that), or is this a general purpose term that's applicable to all inspections. Please [edit] your answer to include some further details.